# ¿Cómo castear una variable unsigned char* var a int?

Tags: c

Tengo una duda sobre castear una variable char a int

Piden escribir una función para imprimir todos los número de un array

Este es el array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stats.h"
#include <stdint.h>

/* Size of the Data Set */
#define SIZE (40)

void main() 
{

    unsigned char test[SIZE] = { 34, 201, 190, 154, 8, 194, 2, 6,
                                114, 88, 45, 76, 123, 87, 25, 23,
                                200, 122, 150, 90, 92, 87, 177, 244,
                                201, 6, 12, 60, 8, 2, 5, 67,
                                  7, 87, 250, 230, 99, 3, 100, 90};

    /* Other Variable Declarations Go Here */
    /* Statistics and Printing Functions Go Here */
    print_array( &test, SIZE);
}
```

Esta es la función

```
void print_array(unsigned char *array, unsigned int length)
{
    int i,j;
    //size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      //printf("array[%d] = %d\r\n ", (int)array[i]);
        printf("%d\r ", (int)array[i]);
    }
}
```

Al compilar genera este resultado:

> stats.c: In function ‘main’: stats.c:42:3: warning: passing argument 1
>   of ‘print_array’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
>   print_array( &test, SIZE); ^ In file included from stats.c:26:0:
>   stats.h:56:6: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type
>   ‘unsigned char (*)[40]’ void print_array(unsigned char *array,
>   unsigned int length); ^

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer el casteo de (unsigned char* a int para poder imprimir los elementos del array?`

```
void print_array(unsigned char *array, unsigned int length)
{
    int i,j;
    //size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
        //printf("array[%d] = %d\r\n ", (int)array[i]);
          printf("%d\r ", (int)array[i]);
    }
}`
```

---

En la función print_array la variable j no cumple la función de segundo item de una matríz porque lo que se desea es hacer que la función imprima el arreglo:

```
unsigned char test[SIZE] = { 34, 201, 190, 154,   8, 194,   2,   6,
                              114, 88,   45,  76, 123,  87,  25,  23,
                              200, 122, 150, 90,   92,  87, 177, 244,
                              201,   6,  12,  60,   8,   2,   5,  67,
                                7,  87, 250, 230,  99,   3, 100,  90};
```

Porque el enunciado, en inglés dice: find_median() - Given an array of data and a length, returns the median value

Para ello desarrollé:

```
void print_array(unsigned char *array, unsigned int length){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("array[%d] = %d\r\n ", i, (int)array[i]);
    }
}
```

Luego en la función main ():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stats.h"
#include <stdint.h>

/* Size of the Data Set */
#define SIZE (40)

void main() {

  unsigned char test[SIZE] = { 34, 201, 190, 154,   8, 194,   2,   6,
                              114, 88,   45,  76, 123,  87,  25,  23,
                              200, 122, 150, 90,   92,  87, 177, 244,
                              201,   6,  12,  60,   8,   2,   5,  67,
                                7,  87, 250, 230,  99,   3, 100,  90};

  /* Other Variable Declarations Go Here */
  /* Statistics and Printing Functions Go Here */
    print_array( test, SIZE);
}
```

Al compilar dió como reusltado:

```
 array[0] = 34
 array[1] = 201
 array[2] = 190
 array[3] = 154
 array[4] = 8
 array[5] = 194
 array[6] = 2
 array[7] = 6
 array[8] = 114
 array[9] = 88
.
.
.
```

¿Por qué con la sentencia `print_array( &test, SIZE);`genera el siguiente mensaje de compilación?

¿ `print_array( &test, SIZE);` no es la forma correcta de llamar a la funión?

stats.c: In function ‘main’:
stats.c:42:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print_array’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   print_array( &test, SIZE);
   ^
In file included from stats.c:26:0:
stats.h:56:6: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char (*)[40]’
 void print_array(unsigned char *array, unsigned  int length);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los arrays en la pila como el de tu código:

```
unsigned char test[SIZE] = /* ... */
```

Reservan espacio para almacenar una serie de elementos en la pila del programa. C va a gestionar este tipo de reservas con un puntero que apunta a la primera posición, de ahí que posteriormente puedas hacer algo tal que `test[5]`.

Como `test` se va a gestionar como si fuese un puntero, para llamar a `print_array` no tienes que usar referencias. La función te pide un puntero que es exactamente lo que tienes, luego la llamada es directa:

```
print_array(test,SIZE);
```

> ¿Por qué con la sentencia print_array( &test, SIZE);genera el siguiente mensaje de compilación?

Se genera una advertencia porque `&` convierte un puntero simple en un puntero doble, y al comilador le rechina un poco que intentes hacer algo tal que:

```
unsigned char ** puntero_doble = &test; 
print_array(puntero_doble,SIZE);
```

¿Por qué? Los tipos no coinciden... y el compilador te está avisando de que *seguramente* hayas metido la pata al realizar la llamada.

> ¿ print_array( &test, SIZE); no es la forma correcta de llamar a la funión?

Obviamente no. La función está esperando un puntero simple de tipo `unsigned char` y eso es exactamente lo que le tienes que pasar... es como si intentases acceder al tren con un billete de metro... va a ser que no.

Las funciones esperan unos tipos determinados y tu tienes que satisfacer ese requisito si quieres que el programa funcione como se espera.